# cannot send udp packets to remote host through wifi on android

Tags: android, sockets

Here is the code: I'd like to send out a string to a remote host 192.168.1.3 at port 12345. But I cannot receive it at the remote host. Please let me know what's missing. thx
btw,I do can send information from android device to the remote host using netcat.  And i also invoked `isReachable()` and it showed that the remote host can be pinged.

```
try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket();

                socket.setBroadcast(false);
                DatagramPacket packet;
                String datas="adasdasdasd";
                packet = new DatagramPacket(datas.getBytes(), datas.length(),InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.3"), 12345);

                socket.send(packet);
                System.out.println("sending");
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testclientnew"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testclientnew.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the android device connected to the local network?

Comment: Yes. I can send information from android device to the remote host using netcat

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions? Have you added the internet permission to the manifest file?

Comment: I just tried to send a message to another application with your code. It works. So you're most likely missing the internet permission in the manifest or not receiving packages at the remote host correctly.

Comment: @NoToast No exception,and I did add the internet permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It's simply because I did not open the netcat correctly at the receiver side. I should use `nc -ul 12345`. I missed the `-u` option which result in my failing in receiving UDP packets.